# simplexml adding a function while generating a report

Tags: php, excel, simplexml

I'm using simplexml to generate an excel report. All columns are being populated from a db.

1. There's one column named inv-numbers that needs an excel function inserted.
2. I would like to insert this function while the report is being created instead of adding it after the report is generated.
3. The excel function I need to add to the inv-numbers column =ROUNDUP(E3-J3-N3-R3-V3-Z3-AD3-AH3-AL3-AP3-AT3-AX3-BB3-BF3-BJ3-BN3-BR3,0) this is the 3rd row. So all rows would need this function but of course row 4 would be - =ROUNDUP(E4-J4-N4-R4-V4-Z4-AD4-AH4-AL4-AP4-AT4-AX4-BB4-BF4-BJ4-BN4-BR4,0) and so on.
4. Is it possible to do this using simplexml?

If it is possible, code examples would be appreciated.

Comment: Why you use simplexml on not [phpexcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) for that?

Comment: This report was created by someone else a long time ago.  I would rather not recreate the report using phpexcel, if it's possible to do what I need to do using simplexml.

Comment: You will need to understand what is the structure of a function inside the XML file :)

Comment: Could you please restate this as a question rather than a "code this for me" request? :)